# Save PHP generated website elements as HTML using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to save website profile page as HTML file using PHP. I checked inspect element, copy html and saved as html file. Its working fine in localhost. I used this script for storing as html file, but the layout of page not working perfectly like inspect element file.

```
<?php
$header = file_get_contents('https://www.domain.com/profile');
file_put_contents('test.html',$header);
?>
```

How can save the html elements like inspect element script using PHP?

Comment: So does this code successfully save the HTML of the page? Or is there some error? If this question is about displaying your test.html as the original website is, you'll have to copy (and possibly modify) all references to CSS and image files, possibly among others.

Comment: Of interest: [PHP tool that saves an entire page](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/phf-demo) into one file (includes source code of tool)

Comment: It saves html file, but when i run the html file its layout and design not properly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to save the CSS file too. With

```
$header = file_get_contents('https://url.com');
```

you only save the index page.